# Jquery Multiplication not working? But addition works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to multiply 2 values from input box and store it in the last row of that column. The **adding works perfectly** for this but the multiplication does not work.

I want to multiply all the row inputs. I got an example for addition why doesn't multiplication work ?

I've tried
**tot *= Number($(this).val()) || 0**  //this does't work. 
**tot = ((tot) * (Number($(this).val()) || 0))**  //this doesn't work.

```
$('table input').on('input', function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); // get tr which contains the input
    var tot = 0; // variable to sore sum
    $('input', $tr).each(function() { // iterate over inputs
        tot += Number($(this).val()) || 0 // i want to multiply here. The addition works perfectly     
    });
    $('td:last', $tr).text(tot); // update last column value
}).trigger('input'); // trigger input to set initial value in columns
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when you are saying `this does't work`?

Comment: Can you add a working code snippet demonstrating the problem?

Comment: i'm using a Backend with ajax so i theres lot of code. Whats happening is that  when i use this  `tot *= Number($(this).val()) || 0` i get the output as **0** so the multiplication doesn't work. I'm supposed to get the value of the 2 inputs multiplicative output . i.e, `500 * 2 = 1000` .Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of addition you are trying to add a `0` when there is no value. So it wont affect anything in the addition.

But if you will try to multiply the whole value will `0` if some input does not have value then the whole value will become a zero, and will remiain zero forever. `Anything * 0 = 0.`

So instead do:

```
tot *= Number($(this).val()) || 1
```

Also in case of multiplication initialize `tot` with a value of `1` and not `0`.

Comment: Omg!! Thank you so much mate it works :D cheers @void your a life saver.

Comment: cheers Void :D ha! you made my day. Glad to be a dev. What a great Industry were in.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this code snippet. Here I assigned `tot = 1`, because multiplication with zero will provide a result of zero. So initialisation must not be zero, and I modified the multiplication statement to

```
"tot *= Number($(this).val())"
```

Final code will be:

```
$('table input').on('input', function() {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
        var tot = 1; //variable to store product
        $('input', $tr).each(function() { 
            tot *= Number($(this).val())      
    });
    $('td:last', $tr).text(tot); 
}).trigger('input');
```

Comment: ohh...that's great...!